# Accessing python containing classes or objects

Tags: python, oop, static-methods

How to access the calling/outer/container python class within current class when added as a property. Consider this example...

```
class a():
    @staticmethod
    def meth():
        print 'Who called me?'

class b():
    my_a = a

class c():
    my_a = a

b.my_a.meth()
>> Who called me?

c.my_a.meth()
>> Who called me?
```

So the question in this example is how to know within a.meth() whether it is being called from class **b** or class **a**?

The above are obviously static classes and methods, would the solution to the above also apply to containing objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no good way to know how the meth() function was accessed.  By the time it is called, it is simply a function.  If you use @classmethod instead, you will at least get the class passed to you, but in this case, they are both the same `a`, so I'm not sure you'll get what you want.

You will likely need to do some more bookkeeping to get the information you want.

Comment: That's what I was struggling with indeed. If you are familiar with Django, I am trying to mirror the built-in functionality of ModelManagers for Model objects. Somehow the default ModelManager ('objects') is able to determine which model it is being called from although the calls are all static. i.e. MyModel.objects.get(id=1). Any pointers to the right part of the django.db modules would be appreciated.

Comment: @sansjoe: I don't have any idea of what Django does, but I know that the simplest and most sane way to do something like this should be creating per-class instances of such "managers" (possibly dynamically using a class-level property defined using a metaclass).

Comment: Yeah, looks like Django creates a number of signals including class_prepared and manually adds a default ModelManager to any Model class. Thanks all!